# ¿Cómo debería hacer para extraer correctamente, de un React FC, la función que trae los documentos de Firebase con onSnapshot? Estoy usando Ionic

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic

Estoy intentando extraer la consulta de una colección de firebase y llevarla fuera del componente pero no logro saber como hacerlo correctamente.

Estoy usando Firebase, Ionic, React.

**Este es mi componente: FACILMENTE PODRIA HACER ESTO O REMPLAZAR EL GET POR ONSNAPSHOT PERO LA IDEA ES PODER EXTRAER LA PARTE DE FIREBASE DEL COMPONENTE A UN ARCHIVO DIFERENTE POR ESO CREE LA FUNCION getList('movies')**

```
...

import { getList } from '../../firebaseConfig';

const Peliculas: React.FC = () => {
  const [listMovies, setListMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([])
  const [newMovie, setNewMovie] = useState<Movie>()

  const listLoading = async () => {
/*    
    try {
      let list:Movie[] = [];
      const res = await firebase.firestore().collection("movies").get();
      res.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push(createMovie({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          description: doc.data().description
        }))
      })
      setListMovies(list)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
*/

    getList("movies").then(result => {
      setListMovies(result)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    listLoading()
  })
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Blank</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonList>
        {listMovies.map((movie) => {
              return (
                <IonItem>
                  <ItemListPelicula movie={movie} delete={() => {}} />
                </IonItem>
              )
            })}
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Peliculas;
```

el otro archivo donde estaría la función para obtener los documentos es este:
**ENTIENDO QUE NO DEBO USAR UNA PROMESA EN EL CASO DE ONSNAPSHOT PERO NO SE COMO HACERLO ENTONCES, PORQUE SI O SI QUIERO USAR ONSNAPSHOT...**

```
...


export async function getList(collection: string) {
  let list: Movie[] = []
  await firebase.firestore().collection(collection)
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      list.push({
        id: doc.id,
        description: doc.data().description,
        title: doc.data().title,
      })
    });
    return list
  }, error => {
    return error;
  })

  return list
}
```

Comment: ¿Porque se requiere usar `onSnapshot()`?, al parecer solo se necesitan consultar documentos;  por otro lado no se ve que se estén usando `react types` adicionales, ¿Porque usar `React.FC`?, saludos

Comment: usar `onSnapshot()` es para poder detectar los cambios en tiempo real, si bien en este caso podría usar directamente un `get` y cumpliria su propocito, quiero ir entendiendo como seria en el caso de usar el `onSnapshot()` en una situacion similar pero en otra parte del proyecto mas adelante. Respecto del `React.FC` es cierto que podria simplemente quitarlo en este caso.

Comment: Claro, se me ocurre  implementar `onSnapshot()` en el método `delete` aquí: `<ItemListPelicula movie={movie} delete={() => {}} />`, con `onSnapshot()` se escucha cuando se elimina un registro `movie` en `firebase`, solo quedaría definir ¿Que se hace después de este evento? Saludos

Comment: En realidad la futura utilizacion del `onSnapshot()` sería en un mini chat que ha de haber y por eso quise ir aplicandolo aqui mismo para ir empezando a entender como separarlo del componente en si... Basicamente eso es lo que quiero lograr entender, como puedo extraer el `onSnapshot()` del propio componente y en el mismo llamarlo por medio de una funcion creada por mi mismo...